# VideoView to Display Embeded Video

Tags: android, android-videoview

In my application I'm getting data from an *webservice* in a format

**e.g.**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3HZP9rOWwk?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The source of IFrame may differ on the basis of different providers for example **vimeo, youtube, dailymotion** etc.
My question is, How to let my application display videos from different sources or Is there any library for uniform loading of videos?

Comment: may you should try vlc api or youtubeplayer api to display it in android

Comment: if the source is not specific to youtube will the app be displaying particular video?

Comment: if the source is not specific to youtube go for vlc api which should work for youtube as well as non youtube data

Answer (score 0):

Just Do it.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadData(videourl, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

E.g

```
 wv.loadData("<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S3HZP9rOWwk?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```